# Get real name from Facebook login to Parse User

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, parse-platform

Working on an application that uses Facebook login. Currently, when a user logs in, an object is added to the User class on Parse that shows the Facebook id. How could I get my application to get the user's real name and save it to this class? Below is the action for the button which triggers the Facebook login. Adding anything to permissions like "first_name" does not work. Any ideas?

```
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
        (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if user == nil {
            NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        } else if user.isNew {
            NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
        } else {
            NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You don't need to ask for additional permissions to get the user's first name since it's public info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to utilize the Facebook API in order to get some of this additional information.

I use this code in one of my apps, which is in Objective-C.

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
            NSString *name = userData["name"];
        }
}];
```

I also use Parse and from this code I store their FacebookID, profile picture, and name.

Comment: Hello Johnathon, I was able to get the first name and last name, but how do I save to the user class. Should I call the [PFuser login] method or is there any other way. Thanks